# Fade-in (gradually) at the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein

I want a function that will **gradually** change opacity from 0 to 1 at the bottom of the page.

I use similar function at the top of my project, but instead of fade-in, I use fade-out. Creating this was fairly easy but fade-in at the bottom of the page with set threshold is a nightmare.

After research I've discovered that it is possible to create fade-out at the bottom of the page using:

```
var scrollBottom: (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop())
```

To set threshold I would have to divide "scrollBottom" by a number. Everything works fine but no matter what, I am not able to change fade-out to fade-in. I was trying to play with color instead of opacity. Changing text from white to black would give me exact same result but I wasn't able to assign separate value from "scrollBottom" to certain color and gradually change it.

After many tries I've came out with solution where I keep the fade-out effect at the bottom of the page, but instead of fading-out text I am fading-out a div with solid color that is above the text layer. It works but I am not happy about the fact that you are not able to highlight the text until opacity is 0, where I can set my div's `display:` to  `none;`

Here is the code:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  $(".h-work").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 320);
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 320) {
    $(".h-work").hide();
  } else {
    $(".h-work").show();
  }

  var t = 320;
  var sb = (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop());
  var f = sb / t;
  $(".hide").css("opacity", f);

  if (sb >= 320) {
    $(".h-work-bottom").hide();
  } else {
    $(".h-work-bottom").show();
  }

  if (f <= 0) {
    $(".hide").hide();
  } else {
    $(".hide").show();
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  height: 400%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-fixed-real {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.h-work {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.h-work-bottom {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 9;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 48px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: #000000;
}

.hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrap-fixed-real h-work">
    <h1>Scroll down</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-fixed-real h-work-bottom">
    <h1>
      <div class="hide"></div>More, even worse projects to come.</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, user is not able to higlight the text at the bottom until `var` `f` reaches 0. I know that, no one is going to even try to select some random text but to me this is not professional. I did same thing but using two different methods. I would really like to have my code to be more consistent.

So here is my question: Can a man achieve same result as you can see in the example above but with text fading-in instead of div fading-out?

**EDIT:** I've seen (literally for a few seconds) a reply from some stranger where he says that `pointer-events: none;` fix the problem with not beeing able to select the text under the div `.cover`. It works! For a now I think that this is the way to go. I do not know, why did you delete your reply though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".h-work-bottom").hide();
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  $(".h-work").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 320);
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 320) {
    $(".h-work").hide();
  } else {
    $(".h-work").show();
  }

  var t = 320;
  var sb = (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop());
  var f = sb / t;

  if (sb >= 320) {
    $(".h-work-bottom").hide();
  } else {
    $(".h-work-bottom").css("opacity", 1 - f);
    $(".h-work-bottom").show();
  }

  if (f <= 0) {
    $(".hide").hide();
  } else {
    $(".hide").show();
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  height: 400%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-fixed-real {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.h-work {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.h-work-bottom {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 9;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 48px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: #000000;
}

.hide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrap-fixed-real h-work">
    <h1>Scroll down</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-fixed-real h-work-bottom">
    <h1>
      More, even worse projects to come.</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Your main problem was that your H1 and div.hide weren't correctly closed, and that you had an absolutely position element inside an element with 0 width.

I've managed to actually just take out the .hide element, and keep the markup just like the top part. Once all that was done, the bottom was fading out instead of in. I had to substract `f` to 1 instead of using `f` to reverse the effect.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an extra `div` element. Just add the line `f = 1-f;` after `var f = sb / t;`. Have a look:

```js
$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  $(".h-work").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 320);
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 320) {
    $(".h-work").hide();
  } else {
    $(".h-work").show();
  }

  var t = 320;
  var sb = (($(document).height() - $(window).height()) - $(window).scrollTop());
  var f = sb / t;
  f = 1-f;
  $(".h-work-bottom h1").css("opacity", f);

  if (sb >= 320) {
    $(".h-work-bottom").hide();
  } else {
    $(".h-work-bottom").show();
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  height: 400%;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap-fixed-real {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.h-work {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.h-work-bottom {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 9;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px 48px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-fixed-real h-work">
  <h1>Scroll down</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrap-fixed-real h-work-bottom">
  <h1>
    More, even worse projects to come.</h1>
</div>
```